# What is the protocol when another user incorporates my answer into an existing answer?

Tags: discussion

I'm asking in relation this question

[In canon, has a Jedi ever killed a Sith using the light side?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/127608/in-canon-has-a-jedi-ever-killed-a-sith-using-the-light-side)

I wrote a [new answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/169887/20774) to that question, and another individual then added my answer to the old, accepted one.

The problem is that it changes the old answer from *maybe* to *yes* and isn't what people voted on back when it was written. Also, it makes my answer redundant. **Should the edit be rolled back?**

Comment: @Möoz - In this instance it wasn't the OP that "stole" the answer, it was another user adding it as an edit to the accepted answer.

Comment: @Valorum Who cares, same issue essentially, no?

Comment: @Möoz - Arguing over petty minutiae is the blood and soul of Meta:SE

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**This was an inappropriate edit for a couple of reasons**

- It dramatically changed the meaning of the existing answer
- It borrowed heavily from a new answer to the same question without offering any attribution, making the OP of that question look (to the casual viewer. e.g. one unfamiliar with how the edit-history button works) like they'd taken the answer from you.

I've [rolled it back](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/127610/revisions) to an earlier version. Kudos on finding a new and potentially better answer to the question within the canon.